# Error The type or namespace name 'name of my tables' could not be found()are you missing a ussing directive or an assembly refrence?)

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

I get this error (The type or namespace name 'name of my tables' could not be found()are you missing a ussing directive or an assembly refrence?)) in Context.cs file when i compile my ASP.NET MVC2 Web Application. I follow these guide http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Setting_up_SubSonic_3.0 but i cant solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error after I made customizations to SQLServer.ttinclude to include only certain tables, but for which I forgot to make corresponding changes in ActiveRecord.tt. If you are just setting up and have made no modifications, probably you are not seeing the error for the same reason. But maybe try reloading your .tt and .ttinclude files from the SubSonic distribution so you are sure you didn't accidentally modify them (other than setting connection string etc.).